# Databinding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am having a trouble databinding in a Text block.

What I want to do is that whenever there is exception occured in any class I want to dispaly in  Text Block but for some reason its not dispalying.

Main.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestingWPF.Main"

      <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="showErr" ObjectType="{x:Type   local:ErrorLog}"         MethodName="GetError"/>
            </Window.Resources>
       <Frame  Name="frame1" Width="620"/>
       <Button  Name="button1"  Click="button1_Click">
       <TextBlock Name="txtBlock6" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource showErr}}"/>
    </Window>
```

Main.xaml.cs

```
    namespace TestingWPF
    {
       public partial class Main : Window
       {
          private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
             frame1.Source =new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);     
          }
       }

      public class ErrorLog 
      {
         private string errorInfo { get; set; }

        public string GetError(string errorMessage)
        {
           return errorInfo =errorMessage;
        }
      }
   }
```

Page1.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="TestingWPF.Page1"
<Button  Name="button1"  Click="button1_Click">
<Button  Name="button2"  Click="button2_Click">
</Page>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```
namespace TestingWPF
{
    public partial class Page1 : Page
     {
        ErrorLog errorLog = new ErrorLog ();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             someMethod1();
        }

        private void someMethod1()
        {
          try
          {
          }
          catch(Expection e)
          {
              errorLog.GetError(e.toString());// This is not dispalying 
          }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             someMethod2();
        }

        private void someMethod2()
        {
            Class2 class2 = new Class2();
            class2.foo();  
        }
     }
}
```

Class2.cs

```
namespace TestingWPF
{
    class Class2
    {
        ErrorLog errorLog = new ErrorLog ();

        public void foo()
       {
         try
         {
          }
          catch(Expection e)
          {
              errorLog.GetError(e.toString());// This is not dispalying 
          }

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the samples on the MSDN - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx) for example?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you actually set the error I only see the GetError method which only returns the same message that you pass to it? I would either add a parameterless `GetError` method or bind to an actual property of the object you are creating, i.e. create a publicly accessible property

```
Error {get;set;}
```

in your ErrorLog class and set that in your SetError method, i.e.

```
 public string SetError(string errorMessage)
 {
    Error = errorMessage;
 }
```

Comment: @As I manually write here I forget to add get and set. I change ErrorLog Class with get set.

Comment: This wont work on it's own, as he is creating multiple instances of the ErrorLog class. He would need to  make sure he is updating the one he is binding to, which is not the case in his examples

Comment: @NETQuestion: Your GetError method expects a parameter which your binding doesn't provide, why don't you have a parameterless GetError method *and* a SetError method?